# How can I merge two MySQL databases, but only when column matches?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've run into an issue after overwriting an old Wordpress site with an updated version. Unfortunately some Advanced Custom Fields values were lost in the process.

I have a db backup of the old site which has the tables for the fields  I need populated with the correct content.

Is there a way for me to merge this old database with the current one based on these conditions:

- Only merge the wp_postmeta table
- Only overwrite `meta_value` where the meta_key is `pdf`
- Touch nothing else

[image: Every meta_value where meta_key is pdf should get updated]

Comment: Yes, you can make an sql query to insert into one db.table from another table with that requeriments.

Comment: This is a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, probably in more than one way.  Here's how I would do it.

- Restore the old database into a separate database (db_old)
- turn off auto commit
- run an update
- check the data
- commit
- Celebrate with some coffee

Untested update statement...

```
UPDATE db.wp_postmeta a
JOIN db_old.wp_postmeta b on a.meta_id = b.meta_id 
and a.post_id = b.post_id
set a.meta_value = b.meta_value
where a.meta_key = 'pdf';
```

Here's the doc refs for Update: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

The update doc refers to `table_reference`, which is documented here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html